Разница между событиями и обратными вызовами
В чём заключается разница между событиями (events) и обратными вызовами (callbacks) в C#?

Я назвал бы "калбек" некой "наружной логикой", которая может выполнится методом в нужный момент. Обычно такая логика одна, под один метод. События - это уже паттерн "publisher/subscriber", где есть тот, кто плодит события (обычно это класс), и куча слушателей, которые выполняют свою логику. Иногда наоборот, куча событий подписываются на один обработчик (например, клик разных кнопок в списке с одинаковой логикой, но разным параметром). Я думаю вам стоит попробовать оба подхода, тогда сразу поймете всю разницу.

Технически ни в чём. И там и там в качестве ссылки на метод или методы используется один и тот же делегат MulticastDelegate.
Как известно любой делегат может быть мультикастом и инвокая тот же экшн можно вызвать сразу несколько колбэков, но обычно так никто не делает.
Логически разница в удобстве применения. В современном коде мало кто колбэки в чистом виде использует. Потому что во-первых, есть события, во-вторых есть асинхронное программирование.
Что касается ключевого слова event - так это просто ограничитель, обязавающий реализовать шаблон проектирования Publisher/Subscriber, а именно вы не сможете инвокнуть делегат события за пределами класса, где он объявлен. А внутри класса сможете, потому что по шаблону сам класс - паблишер, а все остальные сабскрайберы, которым можно только подписываться.
